# Update Automation test results in Qmetry test cases?

Tags: selenium, automation

Update Automation test results in Qmetry test cases?

Is there  any API or methodology that we can update automation test execution results in Qmetry test build?

Following is my automated test case. I want to update relevant Qmetry test case once it runs

```
//=====================================================================

@Test(description = "Test Case No" )
public void As_a_User_I_can_Login_to_System(String environment){
        Users user = new Users("SID_SMITH");
        String name = loginHandler.success_login(user);
        System.out.print("Environment" + environment);
        Assert.assertEquals(name, user.getUserFullName(), "Success");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific? Do you want test results updated after each run? From personal experience using QMetry since some time now, I am a little bit confused, but I can think of some problems you have.
What QMetry platform are you using? Automation studio? Or QMetry test management for Jira?

I am assuming you're asking about test results that get created when a project is run (on QMetry Automation Studio) and tests execution happened. Well in this case, QMetry has TestNG integrated thus it creates (and updates after each run) test results automatically. You can locate them under the folder `test-results` or you can view them by clicking on `Dashboard` icon.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that clarification questions should go into comments. If you cannot comment then you shouldn't misuse the answers/solutions sections as it only results in down votes which means reduced reputation making it harder to earn the sufficient reputation to post comments. Thanks!

Comment: @dferenc Thank you for the clarification. I will make sure this does not get repeated. Should I move it to the comment?

Comment: @donatmeh  I'm referring to update test results in Qmetry Test Management for JIRA

Comment: Ah, so you need Test Management for JIRA integrated with your QMetry Automation studio instance. To do so, please right click on your project and go to properties. Then QAS Project -> JIRA Integration. Fill there the things you need, and on each run of the test (supposing tests are structured in the Test Scenario - Test Case principal) the test cases will be complete and report is always auto generated. Thanks @Ted87

Answer (score 0):

If you are using QMetry Test Management for Jira (QTM4J), you can use the below Automation API to upload the automation test results to QTM4J. This API will automatically create new or reuse existing test case in Test Case module, link the test case to the test cycle and shall upload test execution results to the cycle, along with test case failure results and attachments. [QTM4J supports automation results of Junit, Cucumber, Specflow, Test NG, UFT, QAF](https://qmetrysupport.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/QTM4J/pages/1000899020/Supported+Frameworks+and+Languages).

Here are a few useful blogs, the steps are detailed and you can choose the following options :

- [Automation API Use PostMan or code the API in your Automation Project](https://qmetrysupport.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/QTM4J/pages/1000866944/Import+Results+using+Rest+API)
- [Import automation results directly from Jenkins build](https://qmetrysupport.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/JQTMJP/overview)
- [Using Maven Plugin](https://qmetrysupport.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/QTM4J/pages/1000867001/Import+Test+Results+using+Maven)
- [Upload from QMetry Automation Studio QAS](https://qmetrysupport.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/QAShelp/pages/1039630762/Integration+with+QTM4J+4x)

For more details you can directly reach out to QTM4J support : qmetryforjira@qmetrysupport.atlassian.net, they are very professional and quick on answering questions.